# Want more than 60 results from Google places API

Tags: google-places-api

I m working on an application to present the places around the user's current location.I have referred the google places API and found it great.But the max number of results returned are only 60. I would like to view 500-1000.Is there a provison from google for such stuff.I m ready to pay for such service too

Answer (score 0):

You can use radarSeach like this "service.radarSearch(request, callback);".

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search